# cmd command in wince7

Tags: c++, image, windows-ce, createprocess

I'm trying to run a cmd command in my wince7 machine. 
my code is: (for example)

```
    STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 
    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
    siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 


    TCHAR regsvrActiveXConsole[256] = L"cd";
    if (CreateProcess(L"\\Windows\\cmd.exe", regsvrActiveXConsole ,0,0,false,NULL,0,0,&siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo))
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

and I get: "unrecognized option cd."

Do I miss something? 
Do I need to add something to the image in order to run cmd commands?

Comment: What's your overall goal here? If it's to change the current directory, then not only will this *not* work (because it would change the current directory of a separate process), but you can just call `SetCurrentDirectory()`. Anyway, try typing `cmd cd` from a command prompt and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd` has certain usage rules, it doesn't just execute whatever you pass in arguments, type `cmd /?` in command prompt for more information. To make it execute a command, you need the `/C` option. The valid invocation would be:

```
cmd /C cd
```

i.e.

```
TCHAR regsvrActiveXConsole[256] = L"/C cd";
```